# What's a "hook" in HTML?

Tags: html, angular

In an interview recently a developer asked me what "hooks" Angular has "into HTML." I told him frankly I'd never heard the term "hook" before. I have a few guesses, just from the sound of it, but I'm not going to speculate in an interview.

What is/are a hook/hooks in HTML? I have been doing web development for 20+ years and never heard the term before (or if I heard it before I dismissed it.)

I'm sure it's programmer slang for something I've done a million times and just never heard the term before.

I've looked for the term online but the only definitions I get are vague and general, not plain and specific enough for me. I want a plain English and specific definition, preferably with examples.

Comment: Not sure either but my guess would be that's it's the ng-click you put on your HTML, it does a ''hook'' to your JS. I might be wrong tho.

Comment: hook it mean event

Comment: I think the interviewer just means how does angular connect to the html except the term used is not the best.

Comment: http://www.oakwoodsys.com/beginners-guide-to-angularjs/ go to this webpage and search the word hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only hooks I can see in Angular would be [Lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) as defined in the docs.

But I share ccTag's view that it's definitely not common terminology for HTML template.

Angular templating engine really processes and transforms the whole HTML template into its own structures, so I don't see why a "hook" terminology would make sense in that scenario (it could be - improperly - used for events, dynamic attribute values, pipes or any dynamic feature really).

Comment: Yeah lifecycle hooks would have been my first guess, but, as you mentioned, that doesn't really tie into the template much.

Comment: Yes, lifecycle hooks. That's a good example. Maybe the content and view ready hooks? Keep in mind these are web component hooks and not HTML hooks.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know the things called Lifecycle Hooks in Angular were called that. I somehow don't think that's what he was asking. Still, I'm going to mark this as the best answer, as it at least came closest.

Answer (score 3):

> What is/are a hook/hooks in HTML? I have been doing web development for 20+ years and never heard the term before (or if I heard it before I dismissed it.)

No, we do not use the terms "hooks" in HTML/JavaScript development.As an experienced front-end developer myself. I would have used this as an opportunity to segue way into a discussion about the company's culture and their technical abilities. This would be a blind spot for the interviewer and you need to see what it's hiding.

> I want a plain English and specific definition, preferably with examples.

Don't be that guy. You were already the smartest person in the room. No need to add slag to your dictionary, because it's not going to move you forward in a different interview.

> I told him frankly I'd never heard the term "hook" before.

Angular components have life-cycle hooks.

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Git allows you to use "hooks" to execute scripts during triggers like commit, push and pull. You could have provided this not as an answer, but as an example of how to properly use the term.

https://githooks.com/

Hooks are also used in WordPress to add trigger functions for actions. This allows plug-in developers to add features to the framework. If this interviewer comes from a LAMP stack background working with WordPress, and has done mostly server-side HTML processing, then this could be the origin of their use of the term.

https://www.wpbeginner.com/glossary/hooks/

Comment: Hooks are actually used everywhere, I think it can be defined as a callback that gets called every time a specified event is fired. For example, a lifecycle hook calls the function every time the application state goes from a state to another

Comment: @CristianTraìna the OP is asking specifically how hooks are used in Angular with HTML. There are no hooks used in Angular with HTML. None. So all the OP can do is have a general discussion about the meaning of "hooks", but he can't answer the interviewers question. If you've ever talked to an HR person about a technical role, then you'll understand what I mean. You often scratch your head and ask yourself "What could they possibly be talking about here? I don't want to give a wrong answer" but there is no right answer.

Comment: Yeah, it was about the second part :) I agree

Comment: Don't be the guy that tells people, "Don't be that guy." People say the things they say for very legitimate reasons. For my part, I always take notes during an interview and try to research terms I don't know. It's led to some very interesting side-roads that have enriched my overall knowledge base.

Comment: I'm not saying we shouldn't learn from interviews. I was saying that you shouldn't have any self reflection about your own abilities when other people lack common ground to communicate. Ask lots of questions to ensure the company culture shares in the same interests as your own. A hipster latte drinking tshirt wearing bring your dog and talk slang environment isn't a match for everyone. While others love it. :)